# Meaning of 特异人士

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, lyrics, hong-kong

In the song 皇后大道东 there is a verse which says:

```
冷暖气候同样影响这都市
但是换季可能靠特异人士
```

What are the 特异人士 here on whom the changing of the seasons depends? Google translates this as "special people" but I feel it must have an additional meaning in this context.

Could they be people with great cultural influence such as writers and intellectuals? Special state agents? Some other kind of special individuals?

Edit: Posting the complete lyrics for context.

```
皇后大道西又皇后大道东
皇后大道东转皇后大道中
皇后大道东上为何无皇宫
皇后大道中人民如潮涌

有个贵族朋友在硬币背后
青春不变名字叫做皇后
每次买卖随我到处去奔走
面上没有表情却汇聚成就

知己一声拜拜远去这都市
要靠伟大同志搞搞新意思
照买照卖楼花处处有单位
但是旺角可能要换换名字

皇后大道西又皇后大道东
皇后大道东转皇后大道中
皇后大道东上为何无皇宫
皇后大道中人民如潮涌

这个正义朋友面善又友善
因此批准马匹一周跑两天
百姓也自然要斗快过终点
若做大国公民祇须身有钱

知己一声拜拜远去这都市
要靠伟大同志搞搞新意思
冷暖气候同样影响这都市
但是换季可能靠特异人士

空即是色 色即是空 空即是色 即是色即是空....

皇后大道西又皇后大道东
皇后大道东转皇后大道中
皇后大道东上为何无皇宫
皇后大道中人民如潮涌

这个漂亮朋友道别亦漂亮
夜夜电视萤幕继续旧形象
到了那日同庆个个要鼓掌
硬币上那尊容变烈士铜像

知己一声拜拜远去这都市
要靠伟大同志搞搞新意思
会有铁路城巴也会有的士
但是路线可能要问问何事

皇后大道西又皇后大道东
皇后大道东转皇后大道中
皇后大道东上为何无皇宫
皇后大道中人民如潮涌

皇后大道西又皇后大道东
皇后大道东转皇后大道中
皇后大道东上为何无皇宫
皇后大道中人民如潮涌

皇后大道西又皇后大道东
皇后大道东转皇后大道中
皇后大道东上为何无皇宫
皇后大道中人民如潮涌

皇后大道西又皇后大道东
皇后大道东转皇后大道中
皇后大道东上为何无皇宫
皇后大道中人民如潮涌
```

Comment: Can you post the complete text? I guess it is a satire pointing at the social phenomenon or the political system.

Comment: @r13 posted the complete transcript.

Answer (score 1):

**特异** here refers to superpowers or superhuman abilities.

特异人士 doesn't explicitly mean superheroes, but that is the gist of it.

Answer (score 0):

This song was politically motivated.

My take on these two lines "冷暖气候同样影响这都市 但是换季可能靠特异人士" is that "this city (Hongkong) could be affected by many things such as the weather, but the real (political) changes (after 1997) may be relying on a specific (group of) people (, their will/intention and the policy present).

**More about the song**:

- 《皇后大道东》面世后不久(1991)便随即被中国大陆列为禁歌，直至2000年香港局势大致趋向稳定，《皇后大道东》才终于获解禁。2019年6月19日，因香港发生反修例运动，再度被中国大陆列入禁歌名单当中。
- 文化评论人洛枫认为歌词的政治隐喻轮番指向中国和英国，暗示香港身处中英的角力间不能自主的景况。
- 皇后大道：一条位于香港岛北部的主要道路，指代资本主义[3]
- 皇后大道西：代指英国
- 皇后大道东：代指香港
- 皇后大道中：代指中华人民共和国
- 贵族朋友：时任英女皇伊丽莎白二世
- 在硬币背后：港圆后面的伊丽莎白二世头像
- 伟大同志：罗大佑在接受采访时表示为自身，借以代指香港志士。但此句常被认为指中华人民共和国领导人，且歌曲MV中到这句也用领导人照片作为背景。[28]
- 楼花：房产预售许可证，代指楼市。
- 空即是色，色即是空：“色”借代香港灯红酒绿的生活，罗大佑担心主权移交后“色”就不复存在。
- 漂亮朋友：时任英女皇伊丽莎白二世
- 夜夜电视萤幕继续旧形象：20世纪90年代前[29]香港电视频道每晚结束播出时会展示英女皇的肖像，并播出《天佑女皇》（God Save the Queen）。[30]
- 那日同庆：1997年7月1日主权移交当日

https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%9A%87%E5%90%8E%E5%A4%A7%E9%81%93%E6%9D%B1_(%E6%AD%8C%E6%9B%B2)

Comment: Yes, it seemed that Luo Dayou was using the word "season" in the same way that English speakers might use "climate", with an extended meaning, and making it clear he wasn't talking about the weather.

Comment: I'm wondering if Luo Dayou ever spoke about who the 特异人士 might be.  It could be like the 伟大同志, where you would naturally think communist leadership  (as described in your answer) but he says his actual meaning is completely different.

Comment: "送走皇后迎来皇帝了" - the inner/unspoken feeling of Mr. 羅 and, allow me to repeat his disclose, "伟大同志(typical Hong Konger like him)". But, you are entitled to your own interpretation, as long as you are aware the song was composed to reflect the anxiety of Hong Kong around 1997. :)

Comment: Any interpretations of my own are just guesses and speculation, I'm only too well aware of how something can seem logical and sensible to a non-native speaker, but be completely wrong :-)

Comment: Also, I think my comment on 伟大同志 might have created some misunderstanding, because it was not clear and might have seemed to directly contradict what Mr. Luo has already said, which was in your answer. So, apologies for that.

Comment: No worry, the lyric is full of indirect hints, so no one can be certain except himself I was guessing too. :)